# Progressão aritmética em C

Tags: c, lógica

Olá, sou iniciante e tenho este exercício para fazer em C mas não consigo avançar no meu código:

Escreva um programa que calcule a série:

```
S = 1/1-1/2 + 1/4-1/5 + 1/7-1/8 + 1/10-1/11 + 1/13-1/14 ...
```

com `N` termos, sendo que o valor de `N` é um valor lido a partir do teclado. Escreva o resultado com 6 casas decimais. exemplo de entrada e saída

A única parte de código que consegui fazer até agora:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
void main() {
int n, i; float soma=0;
printf("numero de termos: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
for(i=1; i<n; i++){
    soma = soma + 1.0/(i+1);
}
printf("Resultado: %.6f", soma);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certo, eu analisei o que você fez e o passo não deveria ser de 1 em 1 dentro do loop for, mas de 3 em 3. A operação começa com os denominadores 1 e 2, depois 4 e 5, depois 7 e 8 e assim vai.Além disso, o sinal é trocado também,o primeiro termo do par negativo , o segundo termo do par negativo e assim segue repetidamente. O código deveria ficar assim, fiz os cálculos na calculadora e aparentemente está certo :

´´´

```
#include <stdio.h> 
void main() 
{
    int n, i; float soma=0;
    printf("numero de termos: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=1; i<n; i = i+3)
    {
        soma = soma + (1.0/i);
        soma = soma - (1.0/(i+1));
    }
    printf("Resultado: %.6f", soma);
}
```

´´´